# Create decorator to check if current user is admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am learning python flask and I'm trying to create a decorator to check if the current user is authorized to certain webpage using flask-login.

The problem is that when decorating a function with it my script cannot figure out the endpoint.

My decorator

```
def check_is_admin(func):
    def check(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.is_admin:
            redirect(url_for("login"))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return check
```

And also, while using it, I'm getting following error:
`werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'add_new_trip'. Did you mean 'delete_trip' instead?`

The thing is I completely don't know where is the problem...

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe `return redirect(url_form("login"))`?

Comment: Otherwise you'll still call the function even though the user isn't an admin.

Comment: Yeah, you're missing `return` there...